# THREE.js does not render in the browser

Tags: javascript, browser, three.js

I was watching the tutorial of creating a solar system using the THREE.js library. 
However I could not see the result in the browser's window. Could you, please, help me finding an error in the code?

Here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
   <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Solar System - Intro (1)</title>
        <script src="three.min.js"></script>
    </head>

<body>

<script>
    var scene, camera, render, container, W, H;

    W = parseInt(document.body.clientWidth);
    H = parseInt(document.body.clientHeight);

    container = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(container);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, W / H, 1, 10000);
    camera.position.z = 4300;
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // Sun
    var sun, sun_geom, sun_mat;
    sun_geom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(430, 30, 30);
    sun_mat = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
    sun = new THREE.Mesh(sun_geom, sun_mat);
    scene.add(sun);

    render = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
    render.setSize(W, H);
    container.appendChild(render.domElement);
    animate();

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        render.render(scene, camera);
    }
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

link to the video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kzwEZjVMdkA&list=LLSn1erQiQ7lWhWY9IMOEGTw&index=5

Comment: Are there any errors being reported?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue with your code is that the `document.body.clientHeight` is 0. Use these lines instead:

```
W = parseInt(window.innerWidth);
H = parseInt(window.innerHeight);
```

In addition `THREE.CanvasRenderer has been moved to examples/js/renderers/CanvasRenderer.js` so you need to include that, if you want to use the `CanvasRenderer()`

But you can use the `WebGLRenderer()`:

```
render = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
```

Comment: @gaitat I can't find it under examples/js/renderers/CanvasRenderer.js , is it under something else now? Also, I did replace it with WebGLRenderer(); but however, not my models are dull and just show up as a solid filled colour.

Comment: Do you want to use Canvas rendering or WebGL rendering? The question is pretty old and the Cavas renderer might have been removed. If you want to use WebGL then you probably need to add lights.

Comment: CanvasRenderer was removed in r98